# Delegate an SQS message sent to Lambda to some other service for completion

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a SQS queue attached to a Lambda function, but I would like to delegate the completion of some messages to some other service.

Based on my reading of the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html), specifically:

> When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue.

and

> If your function is throttled, returns an error, or doesn't respond, the message becomes visible again. All messages in a failed batch return to the queue, so your function code must be able to process the same message multiple times without side effects.

Given the above, would it be ok to implement message delegation as follows.

1. Messages handled successfully by the Lambda itself are explicitly deleted to avoid unnecessary retries.
2. For messages requiring delegation, pass the message and the receipt handle on to other service, which will extend the message visibility as needed and delete the message if successful.
3. Return an error to prevent the message batch being automatically deleted.

Would this work?

I really don't like that this would seemingly require one to always return an error. Is there some other way to tie a SQS queue to Lambda, while allowing said Lambda to pass the message onto some other service?

Comment: That might work but it doesn't seem like a very good architecture.  Can you describe what you're trying to do in a bit more detail?   In the absence of more info, here are a few thoughts:  Might it be possible to set up a second queue for the second service?  That way you could just add any jobs to the second queue that need further procesing.  Also, I'm not sure how you're referencing the second service, but you could consider triggering it with SNS so that it is decoupled from the first service.

Comment: @vjones The other service I wish to pass the receipt handle and message to for further processing is a Fargate ECS task.